# 2 includes in PHP Conflict in javascript .show()

Tags: php, javascript, include, conflict

I have a problem regarding javascript .hide() and .show() in "includes" of php. 
It's kind of hard to explain but I'll show the code.

Here is my `toogle_div.js`

```
function toggleWalkin() {
    $('#walk_in').show(500);
    $('#reservation').hide(500);
}

function toggleReservation() {
    $('#reservation').show(500);
    $('#walk_in').hide(500);
}
```

Here is my ToggleMenu()

```
function toggleMenu(){
var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
var specialBox = document.getElementById('contentbox');
overlay.style.opacity = .8;
if(overlay.style.display == "block"){
    overlay.style.display = "none";
    specialBox.style.display = "none";
} else {
    overlay.style.display = "block";
    specialBox.style.display = "block";
}
```

}

Here is my html code:
//Buttons to trigger the show and hide divs

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggleMenu();">Walk-in</a>
<a href="#" onclick="toggleMenu();">Reservation</a>
```

//Content where the information will show

```
                        <div id="button-header">
                        <ul>
                            <li onmousedown="toggleWalkin();">Walk-in</li>
                            <li onmousedown="toggleReservation();">Reservation</li>
                            <li>Seminar Conference Schedule</li>
                            <li>Guest Ledger</li>
                            <li>Guest Database</li>
                            <li>Unavailable Rooms</li>
                            <li>Report Generation</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
<div id="content">
<div id="walk_in">
 Walk in
 <?php include "includes/navigation/walkin.php"; ?>
 </div>
<div id="reservation">
 <?php include "includes/navigation/reservation.php"; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

So basically, whenever I click `Walk-in` the `.show()` function worked. Yet if I clicked  `Reservation`, `.show()` function won't work. 
I realized when I removed the include walkin of the php
     
the reservation of the `.show()` function worked.

In short, those 2 includes are basically conflicting the `.show()`.

Comment: What do toggleMenu() actually do?

Comment: can we see the toogleMenu function?

Comment: I am surprised that walkin gets toggled with `toggleMenu()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters it looks like you need to add  return false; to the end of the onclick as follows:

```
<?php
<a href="#" onclick="toggleMenu(); return false;">Walk-in</a>
```

My best guess w/o seeing the two includes is that you have a HTML error in one of the two include files; missing a closing tag, etc.

Regards,
Kevin

Comment: Silly me, yeah. Took me for almost 5 hours to determine the error. Realizing it, it was on the include files! Thanks :))

Answer (score 0):

Probably after including the php files, there might be some `echo` statements that are not echoing the html in proper format and leading to garbaged html.

Check the source or inspect the page in browser (Press <kbd>F12</kbd> in Chrome/ <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> in firefox). Check whether the concerned div's are as expected.

Also, check for any other `js` error you are getting.